# How to Find the Local IP Address of a New Linux Server for SSH Without Direct Access?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I've recently added a new Linux server to my LAN and I'm looking to manage it via SSH. However, I only have one monitor, which is currently being used by another computer, so I cannot directly access the Linux server's interface to check its local IP address.

How can I get the local IP address of that server?

Comment: If you already cannot log into it (no IP for SSH login) then you will need find a way to deal locally with machine (temporary monitor).

Comment: check your DHCP server for any new IP leases? or, you gave the server a host name when you set it up, see if you can "ping" it using that hostname?

Comment: If you can't access the router or DHCP server (often the same thing on small/home networks), you could also use a tool such as NMAP to scan the network's available IPs to identify the devices on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware of two primary methods for getting the IP address of a specific system on a small/home network.

*Note: While you have not specified this, I have assumed you are working on a small/home network that has a single router also serving DHCP duties on that network. If you are on a business network, talk to your IT people in general, or network people specifically.*

**First Method: Look at the DHCP server/Router admin page**
If you have a single router or modem handling the LAN management/connection duties, and you can login to that device's control panel, there will often be a Clients section. The name of this section may vary by device brand or management software, but there should generally be such a page that will list the IP addresses for clients on your network as well as some limited details regarding those clients that should usually be sufficient to identify the IP address of the device you're trying to find.

**Second Method: Scan the network**
If you do not have access to your LAN router or DHCP server's address/client list, you can install [NMAP](https://nmap.org/download) (ZenMap is the official Windows release complete with GUI) and run a scan of the network. This will usually show at least as much information as a router/DHCP server's client list, and should give you the information you need to identify your new Linux server.

Comment: The first method works for me. I've noticed that my router has an Android app which can list all connected clients along with their IP addresses. This solves my problem, thanks